# SQL Loader from 1 file.dat to multiple tables doesn't work

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I want to load multiple tables from one file (data). It doesnt work. 
I use the when condition. But only the first will load.

For more details:

The scripts SQL for tables:

```
CREATE TABLE TECHNOLOGY
(
     code, dept, salary, hiredate 
);

CREATE TABLE OTHER
(
     code, dept, salary, hiredate 
);
```

The file data ulcase5.dat:

```
100;Thomas;Sales;5000;1000
200;Jason;Technology;5500;2000
300;Mayla;Technology;7000;2000
400;Nisha;Marketing;9500;1000
500; Randy;Technology;6000;3000
600;Bea;Sales;5000;1000
```

The control file :

```
 LOAD DATA
    INFILE 'ulcase5.dat'
   -- BADFILE 'ulcase5.bad'
  -- DISCARDFILE 'ulcase5.dsc'

   ---ONLY THIS TABLE IS LOADER
      INTO TABLE TECHNOLOGY APPEND
      WHEN  salary = 'Technology'
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ";"
    OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'

    (
     code, dept, salary, hiredate 
    )
     -- NEVER LOADED.
 INTO TABLE OTHER 
    WHEN  salary = 'Sales'
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ";"
    OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'

    (
     code, dept, salary, hiredate 
    )
```

Need your help. thanks.

Comment: what say the log file?

Comment: Your input file has 5 columns, but in the control file you only specify 4 (and there is no value that looks like a "date" in the sample data). Shouldn't the `when` clause be something like `when type = 'Technology'`? `salary` seems to be a number column

Answer (score 0):

Move `APPEND` before the `INTO TABLE` line it's currently on:

```
APPEND
INTO TABLE TECHNOLOGY
```

Plus your table, data file and control file are not in sync but I suspect that's an editing issue?

EDIT: Amended based on your comment.

Try replacing this:

```
WHEN  salary = 'Sales'
```

with:

```
WHEN  salary != 'Technology'
```

Comment: Thanks Gary_W. It is a mistake of copy -"APPEND". In my script i use APPEND but all lines 'Technology' are inserted on table Technology. And the other on discard file. I want to have lines 'Technology' on table Technology and all the rest on table 'Other'. I dont understand.